# C++ - For loop not looping

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am working on a hangman program. Up to this point, I have randomly selected a word out of a pool of 10, which gives us "guessWord". I have verified that after the word is selected, I get an accurate number out of "guessWord.size()". In this snippet, while going through the debugger, the program will step into the for loop, test the if function, then drop out of the for loop altogether.

What is going on?

```
for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.size(); ++i)
            {
                if (guessWord.at(i) == guess)
                {
                    soFar.at(i) == guess;
                }
            }
```

Comment: *while going through the debugger,* -- If you don't go through the debugger and just run the program, does the program actually work correctly?

Comment: `soFar.at(i) == guess;` seems like a typo. I am going to guess that you need to use `soFar.push_back(guess);`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It does not. I included that bit to provide I am actually trying lol.

The soFar string starts off as a bunch of asterisks that matches the length of the guessWord. If the user guesses a correct letter, this for loop is supposed to replace an asterisk in the appropriate place where that letter appears in the word. It is not replacing any asterisks at all since the if block is being skipped after the if statement is tested.

Comment: @RSahu Would that apply if soFar is not a vector? soFar, guessWord and guess are all strings in this scenario

Comment: @Andrew Other than `at()` throwing an exception, there is nothing in that loop that would cause it to prematurely exit.

Comment: @Andrew, `std::string` has a `push_back` member function. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this line
    `soFar.at(i) == guess;`
should not have the double equals sign, should be 
    `soFar.at(i) = guess;`

Comment: You're a genius. Every single program I've written for this class, I have been tripped up on just a single character at least once. Thank you!!!!

Comment: How does changing that line cause the loop to keep going?  Yes, it is a mistake, but changing `==` to `=` isn't going to make the loop keep iterating.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Computers do funky things sometimes. Removing the extra equals sign fixed the issue. Now it works like a charm. Maybe the bad logic was just confusing Visual Studio....

Comment: *Maybe the bad logic was just confusing Visual Studio* -- No, there is no magic.  You probably assumed that the loop terminated when it didn't.    No one would be able to write a computer program if things just happen randomly.  You should take a step back and see why such an innocuous change in code supposedly makes the loop iterate.